# Button onclick not firing the event in Android

Tags: android

Here is my button on click listener. I am trying to listen to the onclick event firing. But it is not working. I have tried the method given in develop.android.com. But this method seems to be not working. Can anyone point out the mistake that I am doing here?

```
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      Bundle args = getArguments();
      v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.product_fragment, container, false);          
    Button button = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.buynow_button);
     button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "test", 2000);
        }
    });
    return v;
   }
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are not calling the show function on Toast.

```
   Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "test", 2000).show();
```

Comment: Additionally, if you run into things like this in the future where you think an event is not firing, you can use the Log command to determine if you are successfully entering the function you think you should be. In this example, if you put a Log.d("Debugging", "Handling click event"); inside your onClick(), you would know that you're getting into the function and that there's something wrong with your Toast instead.

Comment: Blumer is exactly right here. You should always first try to debug , only then you should come on a conclusion.

Comment: Sorry. That was my bad. Excuse me for this simple thing. I will avoid this in future

Answer (score 5):

```
Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "test", 2000);
```

Needs to be changed to:

```
Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "test", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```